# How to solve "Kibana server is not ready yet." on windows 10?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, elk

I am complete beginner and don't know anything about configurations or Kibana.

First typed "localhost:5601" on firefox browser.
Then it is showing this message :
[kibana message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foJU3.png)

After surfing google tried this following:

curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_1 -u elastic:pass123
Then got this message :
[user not authorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWzh1.png)

so next I entered user "kibana" in command :
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/.kibana_1 -u kibana:pass123
Then following happened :
[kibana error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiHy7.png)

And so now Iam stuck.

Comment: your DELETE calls to elasticsearch won't solve your problem. Some questions: (1) how do you spin up elasticsearch and kibana? (2) do you have security enabled in elasticsearch? (3) what are the kibana logs saying?

Comment: if you running via VMs check the memory allocated, Kibana needs at least 3gb of RAM to spin up

Comment: @glenacota : I am not getting what you are trying to say. Can you tell me how to check all that?

Comment: @Nate : I am not using VM. And I have 8GB of ram.

Comment: (1) how do you start elasticsearch and kibana? containers? services?  (2) can you check in your elasticsearch.yml configuration file whether you have security enabled? (3) do you have access to the kibana logs? if yes, are there error logs? if yes, what do they say?

Comment: @glenacota To start elasticsearch or kibana : In cmd I cd to the bin directory and type "elasticsearch.bat" or "kibana.bat".

[found this in elastic's config directory]
These following parameters are there in elastic.yaml (I didnot find security parameter in there):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11yOwxoP5aSdprJKwA2tIz25kFAncAE6e/view?usp=share_link

Following is the kibana config file found in kibana's config folder:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZcC-dUp_64sto4mH2bdV3w2Ie613yKO/view?usp=share_link

The log folder of kibana is empty

Comment: do you need to enable security? you can explicitly disable it by adding to the elasticsearch.yml the configuration `xpack.security.enabled: false` BUT IF AND ONLY IF this cluster is not exposed to the Internet or if it's used only for development purposes with no production data

Comment: Share the kibana configuration.

Comment: @glenacota tried adding that parameter, but not working

Comment: @JinnaBalu drive.google.com/file/d/1lZcC-dUp_64sto4mH2bdV3w2Ie613yKO/ 
this is the kibana configuration